# java webservice - wsgen

Tags: java, web-services, wsgen

I've got a task to create a webservice for school. The problem is for some reason I won't get wsgen to work correctly. I've got a class named Warehouse, which is in the package: com.horstmann.corejava.

Now I build this project named Warehouse, and after this I go into commandprompt(cmd) and type "cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_20\bin" where wsgen.exe is.

Next line I type is: "wsgen -cd C:\Users\Julian\Documents\NetbeansProjects\Warehous com.horstmann.corejava.Warehouse"

Now I get an error that he wont find the class, so I change it to: "wsgen -cd C:\Users\Julian\Documents\NetbeansProjects\Warehouse\build\classes com.horstmann.corejava.Warehouse"

The next error I get here is that he wont be able to put the files in the directory...

Anyone got an solution, would be very appriciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [wsgen doc](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/nonav/2.1.2/docs/wsgen.html), there is not `-cd` option. You should use `-cp`, I think.

```
wsgen -cp <location of the jar> com.horstmann.corejava.Warehouse
```

When you use `-cd`, I suspect the command is confused with `-d` which is the target directory where to generate the output files, and explain the second message.

Maybe this [blog](http://www.ewernli.com/web/guest/12) post will provide some help. I was using `wsgen` successfully.

Comment: Thanks, although I did use -cp and not -cd (was type), maybe the problem is my jar file is in the dist folder? Should I show him where the dist folder is then?